# When processing a SSAS cube, how can I gain visibility into progress?

Tags: ssis, ssrs-2008, ssas, olap, olap-cube

When I issue the ProcessFull command, I would like to know the following:

- What is the current dimension being processed
- How many more dimensions will need to be processed before the ProcessFull command completes

What APIs can I use to build my own progress bar?

Answer (score 3):

The way that SSMS and BIDS do this is by listing to trace events (the one that you can see using SQL Profiler).

So you could use AMO to get a list of all the dimensions, cubes, partitions, etc in your database, then when the processing starts you can capture the trace events.

You can actually do this all via AMO if you use the [SessionTrace object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345085%28SQL.90%29.aspx#TRC) and attach event handlers you can listen to the events that relate to methods called within that AMO session.

Comment: Have you seen any open source packages that have created this type of visibility. Would hate to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: No, I am not aware of any other open source projects that have this type of functionality.